# How to embed YouTube video with auto-play thumbnail

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, video, youtube, html5-video

I want to embed a YouTube video but it should have a auto-play poster/thumbnail.

For example https://asana.com/ it has a embedded video but it will play if user clicks on play button. Otherwise another video will keep playing continuously.   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to have one Video autoplaying, and onclick, you want another Video played?

If so, hav'a look at this:

```
<div class="the_container">
    <video style="top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%; cursor: pointer;" id="bg-video" autoplay="true" loop="loop" preload="metadata" muted="muted">
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_stereo.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    </video>
    <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%; display: none;" id="fg-plyr">
        <div data-video-id="bTqVqk7FSmY" data-type="youtube"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        player1 = $('#bg-video');
        player2 = plyr.setup('#fg-plyr')[0];

        player1.on('click', function() {
            document.getElementById("bg-video").pause();
            document.getElementById("fg-plyr").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("bg-video").style.display = "none";
        });
    });
</script>
```

So all you would need to do, is change the first "src", to the video, you want to play in the background, and then change the "data-video-id" to the yt-video-id, you want to play, when you click the BG-Video.
And, you also need to import plyr, so here's'a link to the complete thingy on codepen: http://codepen.io/anthyG/pen/WwJojB

You could add something like a hoverelement, that the user can see over the BG-Video.

You may also consider, using an HTML5-Video-Poster like @mlegg

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay is disabled on most all mobile devices.
Is this what you are looking to do?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_poster